# Can't insert in a table or create a table in MySQL using Python

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have a arduino uno and temp36. I read the sensor value from the arduino serial Monitor with Python. It works!!

But I can't insert in a created MySQL Table  using Python and I don't know why. I have no error or warning.

```
import serial
import time
import MySQLdb

dbhost = 'localhost'
dbname = 'test'
dbuser = 'X'
dbpass = 'Y'
ser = serial.Serial('COM7',9600,timeout=1) # On Ubuntu systems, /dev/ttyACM0 is the default path to the serial device on Arduinos, yours is likely different.
while 1:
time.sleep(1)
the_goods = ser.readline()
str_parts = the_goods.split(' ')
conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = dbhost,
                user = dbuser,
                passwd = dbpass,
                db = dbname)
cursor = conn.cursor ()
sql = "INSERT INTO arduino_temp (temperature) VALUES ('%s');" % (str_parts[0])
print "Number of rows inserted: %d" % cursor.rowcount
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
except:
    pass
cursor.close ()
conn.autocommit=True
conn.close ()
print the_goods
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Those Value in SQL-table need to be plot in php (real time ploting)

Hardware: windows 7, Python 2.7, Python editor:Pyscripter, arduino uno, MySQL Workbench

Comment: You need to start with removing the `try`/`except` blanket exception handling. Your `autocommit` change comes too late to apply to the insert statement.

Comment: you shouldn't string-format the sql-command, use placeholders instead: `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO arduino_temp (temperature) VALUES (%s)', str_parts[0])`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. i´m getting an error: programmingerror:" Table test.arduino_temp does not exist. " What is the meaning of that error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to commit after executing the sql statement:

```
cursor.execute(sql)
cursor.commit()
```

or set `autocommit=True` after the connection is established.

Comment: The OP did try to set `autocommit=True` but does it too late to matter.

Answer (score 1):

If you open database connection it is initially with `autocommit=False` mode, so after you execute SQL statement you must `commit()` it. Also do not `pass` on exception. This way you will not see problems. You can log exception into file. You also use `cursor.rowcount` before you execute INSERT statement. Use it after it.

From your comments it seems that you do not defined `arduino_temp` database. I do not have MySQL database but I have tested such code with PostgreSQL and ODBC driver. You can use it to test your database and driver:

```
import MySQLdb
import traceback


def ensure_table(conn):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM arduino_temp')
        for txt in cursor.fetchall():
            print('Number of already inserted temepratures: %s' % (txt[0]))
    except:
        s = traceback.format_exc()
        print('Problem while counting records:\n%s\n' % (s))
        print('Creating arduino_temp table ...')
        # table arduino_temp does not exist
        # you have to define table there
        # you will probably have to add some columns as:
        #  test_id SERIAL primary key,
        #  test_date timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        # and add index on test_date
        cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE arduino_temp (temperature integer)')
        print('table created')
    cursor.close()


def insert_temperature(conn, temperature):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO arduino_temp (temperature) VALUES (?)", (temperature, ))
    #cursor.execute("INSERT INTO arduino_temp (temperature) VALUES (%s)", (temperature, ))
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO arduino_temp (temperature) VALUES (%d)" % (int(temperature)))
    print("Number of rows inserted: %d" % (cursor.rowcount))
    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()


def main():
    # ...
    conn = MySQLdb.connect (host = dbhost, user = dbuser, passwd = dbpass, db = dbname)
    #conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=isof_test;uid=dbuser;pwd=dbpass')
    ensure_table(conn)
    insert_temperature(conn, 10)


main()
```

If you have problem with database create test code and use small functions. Your code is mixed reading temperature from serial interface and inserting it into database. Make separate functions for each operation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. i´m getting an error: programmingerror:" Table test.arduino_temp does not exist. " What is the meaning of that error?

Comment: It means that in `test` database there is no `arduino_temp` table. You connected to wrong database or misspelled table name or you must create `arduino_temp` table.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answers. but it is not working.

Comment: If you have problem with database create test code and use small functions. Your code is mixed reading temperature from serial interface and inserting it into database. Make separate functions for each operation. Show us error information. Ensure that `arduino_temp` table is in database.

Comment: Hi, i decided to create a new table in phpmyadmin. But only the first data is writing into MysqlTable from phpMyadmin. i don´t know why. It doesn´t work with Workbench. I have no error in python or in mysql.

Comment: when i run your code i have a typeerror: type error: must be string or read-on-buffer,not tuple.

Comment: It it crashes at `execute()` then different db drivers makes prepared statements differently. I have changed code to use Python `%` operator instead of preparing statement, but you can also test version with `%s` instead of `?` in prepared statement. Those prepared versions are in comments. If you have problem then show as much of stacktrace as you can.

Comment: i found out the problem. it was an error in python´s configuration. Thanks very much for your help.